# Military time to am/pm conversion using moment.js

Tags: momentjs

I have a military time that I am trying to convert to a 12 hr am/pm format as shown below

```
console.log(moment("13:00", 'HH:mm').format('HH:mm a'));
console.log(moment("15:00", 'HH:mm').format('HH:mm a'));
```

But I am getting

```
13:00 pm 
15:00 pm
```

as the output, when it should be 01:00 pm and 03:00 pm. Am I missing something on the code ?

Comment: funny thing 24:00 is 'military time' in english.. ^^

Answer (score 20, accepted):

moment docs are pretty clear on formatting - make sure to check them.  "H" is 24 hour time.  You want "h" instead (or hh for 0 prefixed).

```
console.log(moment("13:00", 'HH:mm').format('hh:mm a'));
```

Comment: but why it is taking same date ? For instance I am storing classes usual time frames in timestamp format which will same for each day. But when I use above one, I get current date also. Can you please help me out

Comment: the question/answer here was specific to 12-hour time formatting for a time - it sounds like you have a completely different question related to date / timestamp (and perhaps a question related to `moment()` and not `format()`).  Suggest to ask a new question